# libfaketime and Mac OS, LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, macos, ld-preload

Running Mac OS 10.7.2 and trying to run [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) and nothing happen.  I installed and ran exactly as directed only the time and date stay exactly as are set in the system?  Is anyone else able to successfully run this on OSX?

```
$ date
Mon Jan 30 21:05:09 CST 2012
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" date
Mon Jan 30 21:05:32 CST 2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything on OSX is prefixed DYLD, not LD. And they change the names a bit.. I think what you want is:

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
```

This  is  a  colon  separated  list of dynamic libraries to load before the ones specified in the program.  This lets you test new modules of existing dynamic shared libraries that are used in flat-
namespace images by loading a temporary dynamic shared library with just the new modules.  Note that this has no effect on images built a two-level namespace images using a  dynamic  shared  library unless `DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE` is also used.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it's hard to notice the obvious

Comment: OSX goes out of it's way to be confusing. I'm pretty certain of that

Comment: Yeah how about it, as nice as it is having enterprise supported full featured unix distribution (i.e. OSX) it is insignificant customizations like that which go completely against the advantages of building the OS on a Unix base!!

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: There's much more to it than just renaming environment variables. Apple's using a completely different binary format (Mach-O) and loader (dyld) than Linux uses. They inherited this from NeXTStep, which was developed at a point before using the loader from glibc would have been a viable (or sane) option.